# including external js library showing error in console in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7

[image][image]

I am getting error in the console after including the external js file like this in `default_head_block.xml`

Comment: check this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225917/magento-2-add-external-js-library-in-custom-module?rq=1

Comment: any other solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to include your js using require.config this way:

Create a new phtml file with this content:

```
<script>
   require.config({
       map: {
           '*': {
               'magnific-popup':  'https://cdnjs.....'
           }
       }
   });
</script>
```

Whenever your phtml is executed, above code will make an entry to requirejs-config.js file.

Then you can call that js in any other js file using define:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'magnific-popup' // here the js file is mapped
    ],
    function (
        $,
        popup // you can refer this object to use magnific-popup functions
    ) {
        'use strict';

     // js logic
});
```

In this way your js file will not be included in every page of the site but only in pages you really need it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: this error is comming

Comment: Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ( $,magnificpopup) {
        'use strict';

     // js logic
     $('.blob').magnificPopup({type:'image',delegate:'a',gallery:{enabled:true}});